# how to upgrade the config servers to use WiredTiger in mongodb 3.0.0

Tags: mongodb

I am reading the document [upgrade config servers to use WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/). In the section of "change config server to use WiredTiger", the second step is "stop the last config server listed in the mongos' configDB setting". But the 5th step is to restart the second config server with WiredTiger. I am confused by the sequence of stopping and restarting. Is there problem on this document?

Another question, why the data in config servers should be exported and uploaded manually? Why the data in replicate set should not be exported and uploaded manually? Instead, the data in replicate set can be imported by "Resync a Member of a Replica Set" [please see official doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/)

Comment: Can you show us the document you're using?

Comment: Sorry, re-edited my question again.

Comment: Config servers are not a replica set yet. They are standalone mongod. I am curious why you want to change a config server to WT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current wording in the documented steps may be somewhat confusing given the relative references to first/last/second config servers.

I've added some context for the [documented steps](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#change-config-server-to-use-wiredtiger) below, but you should consider the manual the definitive source. It's also worth noting that you do not have to upgrade the config servers to use WiredTiger (even if your shards are using WiredTiger). Config servers typically have a small data set and are not under high write load.

### Annotated version of the steps from the [MongoDB 3.0 Upgrade Guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#change-config-server-to-use-wiredtiger)

1. [Disable the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharding-balancing-disable-temporarily).

   Disabling the balancer ensures any active migrations have completed.
2. Stop the last config server listed in your mongos' `configDB` setting (will call that `config3` for the purpose of these steps):

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running mmap)
   - `config2` (running mmap)
   - `config3` (stopped)

   Stopping one of the config servers ensures there are no changes to the metadata in the cluster (chunk splits or migrations cannot be committed without all three config servers available).
3. Use `mongodump` to export the config database from config2

   After running the `mongodump` you should have a `dump` directory with bson files.
4. Create a new data directory on `config2`.

   The storage format for WiredTiger data is different from the existing mmap data, and cannot use the same dbpath as mmap.
5. Restart the `config2` server with the WiredTiger and appropriate storage options:

   `mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath <newWiredTigerDBPath> ...`

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running mmap)
   - `config2` (running WiredTiger with no data)
   - `config3` (stopped)

   Note that `config2` doesn't have any data yet, because it has just been started up with the new WiredTiger dbpath.
6. Use `mongorestore` to load the config database backup you created in step 3.

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running mmap)
   - `config2` (running WiredTiger)
   - `config3` (stopped)
7. Shut down `config2`:

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running mmap)
   - `config2` (stopped)
   - `config3` (stopped)

   `config2` is stopped at this point to ensure no metadata changes can happen when we start `config3` up in the next step.
8. Restart `config3`.

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running mmap)
   - `config2` (stopped)
   - `config3` (running mmap)

**(steps 9-15)** These steps are just repeating the same `mongodump` and `mongorestore` for each config server. There's a bit of shuffling to ensure you always have at least one config server available, and do not have all three up while you are still migrating data.

16. Upload the data into `config1`

    At this stage you should have:

    - `config1` (running WiredTiger)
    - `config2` (stopped)
    - `config3` (running WiredTiger)
17. Start `config2`

    With all three config servers are available & upgraded, changes to the sharded cluster metadata can now resume.
18. [Re-enable the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharding-balancing-enable) so normal balancing activity & chunk migration can resume.

Comment: Thanks. "you do not have to upgrade the config servers to use WiredTiger (even if your shards are using WiredTiger)." I am afraid that in the far future (not mongodb 3.0, maybe mongodb 4.0 ), I have to upgrade the config server to use WiredTiger.... If so, I would like to do it now....

Comment: It seems that the three config servers have the **same copy** of the meta data. Why should I **export and import the meta data manually**? The data should be **re-sync-ed** to the config server **without** data?

Comment: [Config servers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/) do not run as replica sets, so there is no automatic process to sync them. To convert data between storage engine formats you need to `mongodump` the data from an mmap instance and then `mongorestore` into a WiredTiger instance. Given the config servers have to be consistent, you could take a different approach and copy the first mongodump to each config server .. but that involves network transfer for data that should already be local to each config server (but not in the desired storage engine format).

Comment: Hi, When I went to step 6. I tried to use "**sudo mongorestore --port 27019 --username allDBsadmin --password esentire --authenticationDatabase admin /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/**" to restore the data. But the error is "**2015-03-16T16:36:01.205-0400 Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.**" I have no idea. @Stennie

Comment: For the auth failed error I would check your credentials by trying to login using the `mongo` shell. Have you upgraded your authSchema? Can you also make sure you are using a 3.0 mongorestore (`mongorestore --version`)? FYI, there should be no need to run `sudo` for  `mongorestore` or `mongodump` (better to fix the file/directory permissions, if incorrect).

Comment: When the config server use MMAP, I already checked these passwords. After I upgraded the config server 2 to use WIredTIger, it fails to authenticate the password. I did not upgrade the authSchema. Here are more details. [link] http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95401/when-upgrading-config-servers-to-use-wiretiger-the-running-config-server-with-w