# When upgrading config servers to use WireTiger, the running config server with wiredtiger does not authenticate the existing pass and user?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, restore, configuration

In order to upgrade mongodb to 3.0.0, I am upgrading my config servers to use WireTiger. I followed the subsection of [Change Config Server to Use WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/). There are 18 steps. I run **mongodump --port 27019 --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --out /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/** to bump the data. When I went to step 6, I tried to use "**mongorestore --port 27019 --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-CR /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/**" to restore the data. 
The error is

> 2015-03-17T17:37:51.963Z I NETWORK  [conn14] end connection 127.0.0.1:56093 (5 connections now open)
>
> 2015-03-17T17:38:01.685Z I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56095 #15 (6 connections now open)
>
> 2015-03-17T17:38:01.687Z I ACCESS   [conn15]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "user", key: "xxx" }
>
> 2015-03-17T17:38:01.687Z I ACCESS   [conn15] Failed to authenticate user@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user@admin
>
> 2015-03-17T17:38:01.687Z I NETWORK  [conn15] end connection 127.0.0.1:56095 (5 connections now open)

I have no idea. But when I start the config server with **MMAP** storage engine, **no errors**. My config file is

`storage:
    dbPath: "/var/data/config1/db"
    engine: "wiredTiger"
    directoryPerDB: true
    journal:
        enabled: true
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/data/config1/log/config1.log"
    logAppend: true
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    port : 27019
    wireObjectCheck : false
    unixDomainSocket:
        enabled : true
security:
    keyFile: "/var/data/config1/keys/mongodb-keyfile"
    authorization: "enabled"
sharding:
    clusterRole: "configsvr"`

Any idea? Should I upgrade the authentication **before** upgrade the config servers to user WiredTiger?  In addition, I used the **same binary /usr/bin/mongod** to generate the config server process and the data server process. Does this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the current [MongoDB 3.0 upgrade instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#change-config-server-to-use-wiredtiger) are missing mention of two important parameters for backing up and restoring users and roles:

- `mongodump --dumpDbUsersAndRoles` (see also: [Required Access to Backup User Data](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongodump/#backup-users)).
- `mongorestore --restoreDbUsersAndRoles` (see also: [Required Access to Restore User Data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#required-access-to-restore-user-data))

I can think of several approaches to fix:

1. If you don't have many user accounts on the config servers, [recreate the administrator & user accounts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/). This isn't ideal, but is probably the fastest approach.
2. Export the users from your mmap database. This is more involved, but saves you recreating the users & roles. I've described steps for this below.
3. Redo the config server migration with the user & role information included. I expect this is the least desirable option.

#### Exporting the users

Assuming you have already upgraded all of your config servers to WiredTiger, here are some steps to add the user information:

1. [Disable the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharding-balancing-disable-temporarily)
2. Stop the last config server listed in your mongos' `configDB` setting (will call that `config3` for the purpose of these steps). This will ensure your sharded cluster metadata remains read-only for the following steps.
3. Re-start `config2` using the mmap data directory

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running WiredTiger)
   - `config2` (running mmap with user/role data)
   - `config3` (stopped)
4. Export the data from `config2`:

   > `mongodump --db config --dumpDbUsersAndRoles --username .. --password ..`

   Add any other parameters needed, eg `--authenticationDatabase ..` if you need to auth against another database.
5. If you have users in the `admin` database on your config server, you will also want to dump that as well.
6. (optional) Remove files from your dump except for the user/role information. If you are **certain** nothing has changed since you did the original migration from mmap to WiredTiger you could skip this step, however it would be safer to not overwrite any existing data.

   Preview the files to remove:

   > find ./dump -type f -not -name "\$admin.system*"

   **WARNING:** removing files, make sure you have previewed to confirm:

   > find ./dump -type f -not -name "\$admin.system*" | xargs rm
7. Re-start `config2` using the wiredTiger storage engine
8. Run: `mongorestore --db config --restoreDbUsersAndRoles dump/config/`

   You should see messages about restoring users & roles, for example:

   > 2015-03-18T02:41:34.887+1100  restoring users from dump/config/$admin.system.users.bson
   >
   > 2015-03-18T02:41:34.887+1100  restoring roles from dump/config/$admin.system.roles.bson
9. Login to `config2` and confirm the users are correctly setup (i.e. auth with admin account, use [`db.getUsers()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getUsers/) to check).

   At this stage you should have:

   - `config1` (running WiredTiger)
   - `config2` (running WiredTiger with user/role data)
   - `config3` (stopped)
10. Copy the `dump` directory to `config1` and repeat the `mongorestore` step.
11. Shutdown `config2` (to keep the sharded cluster metadata readonly for the next step).

    At this stage you should have:

    - `config1` (running WiredTiger with user/role data)
    - `config2` (stopped)
    - `config3` (stopped)
12. Start `config3`. Copy the `dump` directory to `config3`, and repeat the `mongorestore` step.

    At this stage you should have:

    - `config1` (running WiredTiger with user/role data)
    - `config2` (stopped)
    - `config3` (running WiredTiger with user/role data)
13. Start `config2`. At this point all config servers should be online with the user information.
14. [Re-enable the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharding-balancing-enable) so normal balancing activity & chunk migration can resume.

Comment: I've raised an issue to get this fixed in the MongoDB manual: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-5029.

Comment: I run **mongodump --port 27019 --db config --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-CR --dumpDbUsersAndRoles --out /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/** to backup data. It was successful.
I run **mongorestore --port 27019 --db config --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-CR --restoreDbUsersAndRoles /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/** to import data. It failed to find **user@admin**. NO idea.

Comment: Since the users were not created during the initial mongodump, I think you need to remove ` --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-CR` from the mongorestore. Alternatively, start `mongod` without auth enabled, mongorestore the user data, then restart `mongod` with auth enabled.

Comment: The result is :`user@mdb06cmb01p:/var/data/config1$ mongorestore --port 27019 --db admin /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/-----------------2015-03-17T14:10:57.974-0400 building a list of collections to restore from /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/ dir
------------------2015-03-17T14:10:57.974-0400 don't know what to do with subdirectory "/var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/admin", skipping...
-----------------2015-03-17T14:10:57.975-0400 done`

Comment: I run **mongodump --port 27019 --db admin --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-CR --dumpDbUsersAndRoles --out /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/** to backup data. It was successful. I run **mongorestore --port 27019 --db admin /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/** to import data. The result is **2015-03-17T14:17:13.797-0400 don't know what to do with subdirectory "/var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/admin", skipping...**. NO idea.

Comment: For the restore path you need to include the database name in the dump directory, i.e.: `mongorestore --port 27019 --db admin /var/data/config1/mongodump-15-03-16/admin` . In my example it was `dump/config/`.

Comment: The result is **2015-03-17T14:29:08.270-0400 Failed: error getting auth version of server: not authorized on admin to execute command { getParameter: 1, authSchemaVersion: 1 }**. In fact, I disabled auth. The config file is following: **security:
    keyFile: "/var/data/config1/keys/mongodb-keyfile"
    authorization : "disabled"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22032/discussion-between-chengcheng-pei-and-stennie).

Comment: In the step 7, the config 2 has NO data at all. I am not sure whether config 2 has user and password information.

Comment: I deleted **keyFile: "/var/data/config1/keys/mongodb-keyfile"** in my config file to disable auth totally. Now, config server 2 can import the data now.....

Comment: @ChengchengPei Apologies for not replying sooner .. out at meetings :). `--keyfile` implies `--auth` so if you want to fully disable you need to remove both options when starting `mongod`. It sounds like you were able to resolve your issue now?

Comment: Yes, I resolve the issue of importing the backup data to my config servers with WT... Thanks.

Comment: I have another issue.. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95591/in-mongodb-is-sh-getbalancerstate-is-false-the-same-as-sh-isbanlancerrunni Thanks. @Stennie