# In mongodb, is "sh.getBalancerState() is false" the same as "sh.isBanlancerRunning is false"?

Tags: mongodb, linux, migration

During upgrading config servers to use WiredTIger, I stopped balancer using **sh.setBalancerState(false)**, and then I run **sh.getBalancerState()**. The output is **false**. Does this mean the balancer is not running? After this, I just started to upgrade the config servers to use WiredTiger. But after reading the document carefully, I am not sure whether **no migrations are in progress after running sh.setBalancerState(false)**? If **some migrations are running**, but I backup the config data and stopped the config servers one by one. What is the bad effect? Now the config servers are all up with WiredTiger, how to check whether the config servers have the same data, especially config data, meta data....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify that no migrations are running by checking the balance with

```
 sh.isBalancerRunning()
```

which is `true` if chunks are being migrated and `false` if not. Using `BalancerState` only shows you if it is enabled or disabled, not its current run state. While it depends on what the specific documentation says, I'd probably feel safer setting the balancer state to false, checking the migration status with the above command, and then stopping it:

```
 sh.stopBalancer()
```

So now that we have the proper method clarified,

> What is the bad effect?

I'm not too sure how gracefully MongoDB would potentially handle this issue.  However, you should be able to find the [steps that occur during a migration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/#chunk-migration) in your log.

Always check the logs!

**Update:** As specified by the OP, you can also use `sh.status()` if this work occurred in the last 24 hours to check if there are any recorded errors in migrations from the balancer. If > 24 hours, go check the logs.

**Update 2:** Marcus clarified in the comments that partial migrations are not possible, so this should not be a concern.

Comment: When I run **sh.status()** against each config server, the output was **  balancer:
 Currently enabled:  yes
 Currently running:  no
 Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
 Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
  No recent migrations
**. Does it means there are no bad effect?  In addition, I have not enable partition on replication shard now. As for config servers, I have no idea how to check whether there are chunks being partially migrated.

Comment: If this work occurred in the last 24 hours, then it appears you got off lucky.

Comment: Chunks can't be partially migrated. The metadata is only updated after a chunk is fully migrated and only after an successful update of the metadata the chunk is deleted on the original server.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad happened even if you took the config server offline during a chunk migration. In order for a chunk to be marked as migrated, *all three* config servers need to be up (Contrary to popular belief they do **not** form a replica set.).

(The following is a tiny bit simplified for the sake of shortness.)
When a chunk is moved, a global (read cluster wide) lock is written to the config servers. Then, the chunk gets *copied* over to the target machine. Next, the metadata gets updated so that every `mongos` asking for data contained in that chunk is pointed to the new server. Only after a successful metadata update, the chunk gets deleted on the old machine. So if anything goes wrong during the chunk migration, the metadata will always point to the correct location, while the lock prevents any data to be written to the chunk. I am not sure when the lock is lifted, but iirc it is done after the metadata update.

So – since all three config servers need to be online for metadata updates – as soon as you put a config server offline, you prevent any chunk migrations from taking effect.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very detailed. How can I know the details of process of mongodb operations. Could you please suggest some books, materials, and so on.....?

Comment: http://university.mongodb.com is an awesome place to start. Choose classes depending on your background. I'd suggest taking m102 even when you are a developer and one of the m101 classes even when you are a DBA.

Comment: Then go ahead. M202 is really worth it. After that, the DBA is easy.